# How to call a JS function when my form is submited

Tags: javascript

I have this code to validate and submit a contact form:

```js
form_valid: function() {
  if (
    this.form_data.nombre &&
    this.form_data.empresa &&
    this.form_data.email &&
    this.form_data.rubro &&
    this.form_data.telefono &&
    this.form_data.consulta_por &&
    this.form_data.msg &&
    this.form_data.rcapt_response
  ) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

But I need to call another function when this function is on "true". I don't know if I can write:

```js
return true;
return function2();
```

or if I need to write another function that checked:

```js
if (form_valid() === true) {
  function2();
}
```

Comment: Example one won't work. Once you return, the code will stop executing in that block. Use your second example.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72927267/3807365) help? It's how to check form on submit then cancel or go ahead with submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function form_valid() {
  const data = this.form_data
  return (
    data.empresa &&
    data.email &&
    data.rubro &&
    data.telefono &&
    data.consulta_por &&
    data.msg &&
    data.rcapt_response
  )
}

// Return the result
return form_valid() && my_other_function()
// OR if you want to store the result in a variable instead of returning it
const result = form_valid() && my_other_function()
```

`&&` will continue execution until a [falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy#the_logical_and_operator) is encountered, so this will return `false` if `form_valid()` returns `false`, or call  `my_other_function()` if it returns `true`. Of course there's nothing wrong with an `if`-statement either, this is just one possible option.

Another option could be to chain one more `&&` at the end of the `form_valid()` function, like this: `return (... && data.rcapt_response && my_other_function())`, but I wouldn't do that unless it's logically a part of ensuring that the form is valid.

Comment: Thanks, this method solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

Put the call to the other function in the `return` statement.

```
if (...) {
    return function2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should function2 when function returns true.

```
if(function()){
  function2();
}
```

Comment: This could solve the problem but it doesn't relate to the title of the question at least, perhaps describe why you think the question is wrong from the sample code, before giving you answer?