# how to check the value of input type number after submitting it before without page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a JS self-learner. Currently jQuery. So please don't downgrade me. I made an age checker app. But the combination input type number + submit button only works after a page refresh. Is it possible to change the age after submitting it once and see the style changes without a page reload?

**What I mean is that after loading the page, my app works only once. Then console log doesn't show any change in the input field and clicking submit.**

```
      <div class="container">
      <form>
        <label for="age">Check your age</label>
        <input type="number" min="5" max="100" id="ageInput" onfocus="this.value=''">
        <input id="inpBtn" type="button" value="Submit">
      </form>
      <div id="underage">
        <p>You need to get older. You're underage.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="ofAge">
        <p>You are good to go.</p>
      </div>
        <div id="tooOld">
          <p>You are too old for this club</p>
        </div>
```

```
  let ageInput = document.querySelector("#ageInput").value;


  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#inpBtn").click(function(){
  console.log(ageInput);

      if(ageInput < 18) {
        $("#underage").css("color", "red");
        console.log("under 18");
      } else if (ageInput >= 18 && ageInput < 80) {
        $("#ofAge").css("color", "green")
        console.log("good to go");
      } else {
        $("#tooOld").css("color", "gray")
        console.log("too old");
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: I think you need to disable the default behavior, check [Stop form refreshing page on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454310/stop-form-refreshing-page-on-submit)

Comment: Also `.click()` is deprecated .. Use `.on("#inpBtn", "click", function(){ ... })`

Comment: See how I handle form, submit event (not click), and canceling in a recent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72927267/3807365)

Comment: Listen for the [submit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event) event and handle your logic from there.  `$('form').on('submit', function(event) { })`

Comment: @Zak just FYI, [`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click) is in no way deprecated. Your use of `on()` is also invalid in that example.

Comment: You need to check the value of `#ageInput` *inside* your click event handler, otherwise it will only ever contain the value the field has when the page loads.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan but the condition for #ageInput is within the even listener

Comment: @TomDev but you're reading the value of `#ageInput` only once, whenever your page loads. You need to check the value whenever you click your button.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier when I put my conditions into the body of your function it stopped working. I removed the click event because "submit" will be the event, right?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan [jQuery Migration to 3](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/main/warnings.md#user-content-shorthand-deprecated-v3-jqmigrate-jqueryfnclick-event-shorthand-is-deprecated) -- *"Solution: Instead of .click(fn) use .on("click", fn). Instead of .click() use .trigger("click")."* -- In certain instances .. You will come across a console warning that `.click()` is deprecated ..

Comment: @Zak thanks I stand corrected. It should really be updated in the API docs too in that case.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan -- And I use `$(document).on("click","#element",function() {` because it listens to the document for a click .. Even if `#element` doesn't exist -- yet.  Extremely useful, because you can still detect the document click, even if your element isn't there. I haven't experienced any overhead difference, but I assume since it's listening to every click, there might be some negligible overhead.

Comment: Agreed, however my previous comment regarding invalid use of `on()` was because you've put the selector first - it should be the event name

Comment: Good catch! -- I would edit, but alas 5 min = permanent comment!  Fingers moving faster than brain in that moment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue in your code is that you only retrieve the value of `#ageInput` once, when the page loads. This means that when your click event occurs it will ignore the value the user typed in to the field.

Also note that as the error messages are hidden until required, you can set their colours once using CSS, and not in JS every time the event happens. Then your code becomes simpler as it just hides/shows the validation error as necessary.

Finally, when working with a form it's better practice to hook your logic to the `submit` event of the form. This allows users to submit the form using the return key of their keyboard, amongst other accessibility improvements. To stop the form actually being submit, call `preventDefault()` on the event that's passed to the handler as an argument.

Here's a working example with all the above points included:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $ageInput = $("#ageInput");

  $("form").on('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.error').hide(); 
      
    let ageInput = $ageInput.val();
    if (ageInput < 18) {
      $("#underage").show();
    } else if (ageInput >= 18 && ageInput < 80) {
      $("#ofAge").show();
    } else {
      $("#tooOld").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.error { display: none; }
#underage.error { color: red; }
#ofAge.error { color: green; }
#tooOld.error { color: gray; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <label for="age">Check your age</label>
    <input type="number" min="5" max="100" id="ageInput" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <div class="error" id="underage">
    <p>You need to get older. You're underage.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="error"  id="ofAge">
    <p>You are good to go.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="error"  id="tooOld">
    <p>You are too old for this club</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rory McCrossan . This is the effect I wanted to achieve.